# R turn value of cell into equivalent number of rows for correlation

Tags: r, correlation, tidy

Here is the head of my df, n = 40:

```
structure(list(Code = c("75", "75", "75", "75", "75", "75", "75", 
"75", "75", "75", "75", "75", "75", "R009", "R009", "R009", "R009", 
"R009", "R009", "R009", "R009", "R009", "R009", "R009", "R009", 
"R009", "R015", "R015", "R015", "R015", "R015", "R015", "R015", 
"R015", "R019", "R019", "R019", "R019", "R019", "R019"), Name = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "a", 
"f", "g", "h", "i", "k", "l", "m", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"
), n = c(41L, 14L, 7L, 5L, 11L, 138L, 4L, 92L, 19L, 10L, 167L, 
67L, 62L, 3L, 1L, 35L, 6L, 125L, 43L, 4L, 44L, 86L, 8L, 33L, 
37L, 13L, 8L, 32L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 17L, 2L, 7L, 45L, 14L, 10L, 8L, 
15L, 228L)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), groups = structure(list(
    Code = c("75", "R009", "R015", "R019"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:13, 14:26, 27:34, 35:40), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And here is a screenshot:

[image]

I'm trying to turn that n value into the equivalent number of rows. So in this screenshot, I'd like Code == 75 and Name = "a" to be repeated as 41 rows in the dataframe.

The reason I'm trying to do this is because I want to see if there is a strong correlation between Code and Name. So after I have a long dataframe with lots of rows, I plan to use the cor function like this:

```
cor(df$Code, df$Name)
```

But because cor I think is going to give me a rejection because Name is not numeric I think I will first have to convert all the Names to numeric values.

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(Name = case_when(Name == "a" ~ 1, 
                          Name == "b" ~ 2,
                          Name == "c" ~ 3,
                          Name == "d" ~ 4,
                          Name == "e" ~ 5,
                          Name == "f" ~ 6,
                          Name == "g" ~ 7,
                          Name == "h" ~ 8,
                          Name == "i" ~ 9,
                          Name == "j" ~ 10,
                          Name == "k" ~ 11,
                          Name == "l" ~ 12,
                          Name == "m" ~ 13))
```

How do I turn the n value in the dataframe into the equivalent number of rows?

And also, does this workflow make sense? Is there a shortcut to find correlation here besides turning the summary dataframe into more like "raw" data, then converting types to numeric values, then comparing two vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to replicate, use `uncount` after `ungroup`ing

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    ungroup %>%
    uncount(n)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1,467 x 2
   Code   Name
   <chr> <dbl>
 1 75        1
 2 75        1
 3 75        1
 4 75        1
 5 75        1
 6 75        1
 7 75        1
 8 75        1
 9 75        1
10 75        1
# … with 1,457 more rows
```

Comment: awesome thanks I didn't know there was an uncount(n) option like this. Quick question why is ungroup not ungroup() with the parenthesis

Comment: @hachiko you can use either way to invoke within `%>%` (for certain functions)

Comment: @hachiko The behavior may be different with `|>` though